# mutate_if, across or map_if where want to process the iteration conditional on value in another field

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Simple example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  x = 1:3,
  y = c(1, 0, 1),
  z = 1:3
) %>% group_by(x) %>% nest

mydf %>% mutate(blah = map_dbl(.x = data, ~ .x$z * 2))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   x [3]
      x data              blah
  <int> <list>           <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [1 × 2]>     2
2     2 <tibble [1 × 2]>     4
3     3 <tibble [1 × 2]>     6
```

I would like to mutate or map conditional on y. If y=1, then process with .x * 2 else (y = 0) then just use NA.

Desired result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   x [3]
      x data              blah
  <int> <list>           <dbl>
1     1 <tibble [1 × 2]>     2
2     2 <tibble [1 × 2]>     NA
3     3 <tibble [1 × 2]>     6
```

Should I use mutate_if, mutate_across, map_if? How can I get this result?

Comment: I understand this is a simplified example, but could you use `dplyr::case_when()` on your real data? i.e., `mydf %>% mutate(blah = case_when(y == 0 ~ NA, y == 1 ~ x * 2, TRUE ~ NA)`

Comment: I posted this prematurely without specifying was working with a df list column, hence using purrr. Have clarified that now with the code example, sorry about that.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the OP needs to retain the `map` model in their real use case, `map2()` is one possibility...

```
mydf %>% mutate(blah = map2(x, y, ~ifelse(.y == 1, .x * 2, NA)))
  x y blah
1 1 1    2
2 2 0   NA
3 3 1    6
```

Comment: Based on the OP's data, it would be `mydf %>% mutate(blah  = map2_dbl(data, x, ~ case_when(.x$y == 1~  .y *2, TRUE ~ 0)))`

Comment: @akrun OP modified their post to indicate `y` was a tibble after I posted and they had accepted my answer.  But yes, your edit seems appropriate.

Comment: I guess that would be the reason. Thanks for clarifying